# ¿Cómo hacer un borde personalizado en CSS quitando ciertas zonas?

Tags: css

[image: Estas son las zonas que me gustaria quitar del borde]

Hola, estoy realizando el videojuego Snake, y me he encontrado con el siguiente problema.
Mi serpiente tiene que chocarse con los bordes y morir, menos con los dos cuadrados pintados en rojo, por ahí debe colarse y pasar al otro lado. Me gustaría poder modificar el borde del CSS para dejar hueco en esos sitios para dar a entender al jugador que puede pasar por ahí. He intentado hacerlo con imágenes editadas pero no he sido capaz.

Comment: Si agregas lo que llevas seguro es más fácil que alguien te pueda ayudar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

creo que no puedes manipular los bordes como deseas hacerlo, pero lo que se me viene a la mente es tener un div interno que se superponga a los bordes que no deseas mostrar (también se podría realizar con dos div, uno para cada lado).

El código para realizar mi sugerencia seria:

```html
<div style="
        border: 2px solid #000;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        position: relative;
    ">
  <div style="
      height: 20px;
      width: 204px;
      position: absolute;
      background: white;
      left: -2px;
      bottom: 45%;
     ">
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviamente es solo un ejemplo lo ideal seria que manejes clases.